# Let $f : R \to R$ be a continuously differentiable function such that $|f(x)-f(y)| \geq |x-y$| for all x,y $\in R$.

Tags: calculus

Let $f : R \to R$ be a continuously differentiable function such that $|f(x)-f(y)| \geq |x-y$| for all x,y $\in R$. Then i have to find number of solutions of $f'(x)=   \frac {1}{2} $

**Attempt**

I thought of using mean value theorem.i write as
$\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|} = |f'(c)|$, where c lies between x and y
Now to satisfy with question i need to have $f'(c) \geq 1$. So how can it be $\frac{1}{2}$. Is this right way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: The mean value theorem only tells you that for every $x,y$ we have $|f'(c)|\ge 1$ for *some* $c$ between $x$ and $y$. We don't know too much more about $c$, so we're pretty much stuck going this route. Instead, you could prove directly that $|f'(x)|\ge 1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @JoeyZou Sorry i could not understand

Comment: Which part? The part about why your current route won't work, or the alternative suggestion (that would work)?

Comment: Part about current route

Comment: The mean value theorem says that for every $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists *some* $c$ between $x$ and $y$ such that $f(x)-f(y) = f'(c)(x-y)$. But apart from $c$ being between $x$ and $y$, we don't know *anything* else about $c$. So we can't really say anything.

Comment: Anyway, what do you think the answer should be? If you think the answer should be zero, then you want to prove that $f'(x) = \frac{1}{2}$ is impossible. If you think the answer should be more than zero, then you want to prove that $f'(x) = \frac{1}{2}$ is possible. Your intuition on the problem will matter a lot towards what direction you take to solve it.

Comment: So How do i do it. I have no other idea'

Comment: Suppose I told you that you can prove that $|f'(x)|\ge 1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Would that tell you how many solutions there are to $f'(x) = \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: What Joey said is true, but note that it holds for -every- interval containing a given $x$. Thus if the derivative is continuous, $f'(x) \geq 1$.

Comment: @JoeyZou if derivative is greater than 1 , then it can not be equal to 1/2

Comment: @vhspdfg That's a great point; thanks for catching that! If $f$ is continuously differentiable, then a mean value theorem type of argument can certainly work.

Comment: Anyway @TaylorTed, you can prove that $|f'(x)|\ge 1$ for all $x$, either directly, or through a mean value theorem type of argument (using the hint in vhspdfg's comment). Once you have proven that, then, like you said, we cannot have $f'(x) = \frac{1}{2}$. I've left enough comments now, so best of luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pose $x = t + h$ and $y = t$. You get $\frac{|f(t+h) - f(t)|}{|h|} \geq 1$ for every $t,h$ real numbers. Take the limit $h \to 0$, you get $f'(t) \geq 1$ for every $t$ real. So there are no solutions for the requested equation.